# CSS selector for anchor element using document fragment

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Consider the following sample code

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#s1">First Section</a>
        <a href="#s2">Section 2</a>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section id="s1">
            <p>Example paragraph
            <p>Paragraph 2
        </section>
        <section id="s2">
            <p>Example paragraph
            <p>Paragraph 2
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

I can select the `section` that is selected with

```
section {
    background: #fff;
}

section:target {
    background: #f00;
}
```

But I want to target the `a` that selected it using **only** HTML/CSS, which I could imagine being like

```
a[href=:target] {
    font-weight: bold;  
}
```

or

```
a:target(href) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The only solution I could come up with is

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="s1"><div id="s2">
        <nav>
            <a href="#s1">First Section</a>
            <a href="#s2">Section 2</a>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <section name="s1">
                <p>Example paragraph
                <p>Paragraph 2
            </section>
            <section name="s2">
                <p>Example paragraph
                <p>Paragraph 2
            </section>
        </main>
    </div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#s1:target a[href="#s1"],
#s2:target a[href="#s2"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}

section {
    background: #fff;
}

#s1:target section[name="s1"],
#s2:target section[name="s2"] {
    background: #f00;
}
```

I don't like this, however, because it introduces needless elements (the `div`s to target).

Is there a clean way to do this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the `:target` pseudo-class exists for matching a named anchor or an element with an ID corresponding to the current URL fragment, CSS does not provide a selector for matching links that point to the current URL fragment.

There is no clean way to do this without JavaScript. I would heavily prefer using JavaScript over polluting the markup with unsemantic elements and invalid attributes for the sake of accommodating CSS (`section` elements cannot have `name` attributes).

The `hashchange` event is [well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange), so if you can afford it it's simply a matter of listening for that event and toggling a class on the right element:

```
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav > a');

window.onhashchange = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
        if (navLinks[i].href.match(/(#.*)/)[1] == window.location.hash) {
            navLinks[i].className = 'selected';
        } else {
            navLinks[i].className = '';
        }
    }
};
```

```js
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav > a');

window.onhashchange = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
        if (navLinks[i].href.match(/(#.*)/)[1] == window.location.hash) {
            navLinks[i].className = 'selected';
        } else {
            navLinks[i].className = '';
        }
    }
};
```

```css
section {
    background: #fff;
}

section:target {
    background: #f00;
}

a.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#s1">First Section</a>
    <a href="#s2">Section 2</a>
</nav>
<main>
    <section id="s1">
        <p>Example paragraph
        <p>Paragraph 2
    </section>
    <section id="s2">
        <p>Example paragraph
        <p>Paragraph 2
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Selectors 4 originally had a reference combinator that would do exactly what you want, assuming the link pointed to an element that would match `:target`: `a:has(/href/ :target)` but 1) it was dropped due to poor definition and lack of interest 2) it does not support named anchors, and 3) even if it were implemented, a selector like that would almost certainly not be usable in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on BoltClock code, for 2021:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", event => {
    document.querySelectorAll("nav > a").forEach(link => {
        if (new URL(link).hash == new URL(event.newURL).hash) {
            link.classList.add("selected");
        } else {
            link.classList.remove("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

You probably also want to set it on load

```
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll("nav > a")) {
    if (new URL(link).hash == location.hash) {
        link.classList.add("selected");
        break;
    }
};
```